# VB.Net ListView Select Item with Button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Note: There was not any question with this kind of problem here or anywhere...

Ok, so I made my listview, and it's delete and edit events are working properly, now I want to implement a possibility for user to mark an element as "default".

`D`, `E` and `Def` are buttons

```
Reference
----------------------------------------------------------------
- ref1  - somevalue - somevalue - somevalue - [D] - [E] - [Def]
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

so that would be a row from a table, I made delete and edit work by handling events from listview,

```
Private Sub lvMain_ItemDelete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles lvMain.ItemDeleting
   Dim refFac As new ReferenceFactory
   refFac.Delete(e.Keys(0))
EndSub
```

similar for Editing. But now when I try to get values from Default button, the button wont even do anything...
This is the code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtDefault" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Default16.png" CommandName="Default" />
```

and for my logic:

```
Public Sub ibtDefault_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs )
   SelectedRef.Name = "Test"
End Sub
```

I just wanted to test it whether it will run or not by changing the value of my global string that will show which Reference is made default. But it wont even do that...
Then I tried with Commands.

```
Private Sub lvMain_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles lvMain.ItemCommand
   If e.CommandName = "Default" Then
      'Dim refID As New Integer
      'Dim refer As ListViewItem
      'refer = e.Item

      SelectedRef.Name = "Test"
   End If
End Sub
```

But this wont run either... What am I doing wrong here :S

Basically what I want to is that on click i save `Reference` `Name` and `ID` in two global variables i prepared.

Thanks

Comment: When you debug the code can you step into the ItemCommand event? Are you posting back at all, and is your listview repopulated? I also know that Default is a reserved word and that may be messing with your code.

Comment: Hmmm I totally forgot about that... I'll attempt with some other words and will debug to check for details. Will come back with more info.

Comment: That was it... It worked, although I'll have to find a way to refresh page in order for the value to show on page. If you post that as answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default is a reserved word and may be messing with your code. When you run through your ItemCommand event, you can rebind the data at the end of it and it should refresh your page.